# Salesforce connector in google sheets to get all events

Tags: java, google-sheets, salesforce, google-sheets-api, salesforce-lightning

I am using the extension Salesforce connect to connect google sheets to Salesforce. I have to write a SOQL query to get all events grouped by event owner and import it ti google sheet using Salesforce connect. Its hard to write a query on event, some fields like status are in activities. Please advice how to get events from salesforce using SOQL query and including fields like status in the query

Comment: Correct, Events don't have Status. Tasks can be not started/in progress/completed but events... "just are"? they're completed when End Date is in the past. Unless you created a custom field the question is unclear, what exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to get events where status  = show/no show/meeting scheduled. I can do this in report. There is a status field but i need to write a soql query to do this

Comment: What's the report type. "Tasks and Events", "Events with Invitees" or if something custom - can you check it in Setup -> Report Types? "Tasks and Events" will show a Status column but it'll be Task-related, for Event rows it's should be empty. Unless you added custom `Status__c` field I guess. If you're using "Events with Invitees" - check https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm out

Comment: What do you get with `SELECT FIELDS(ALL) FROM Event LIMIT 200`? Or `FIELDS(CUSTOM)`? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fields.htm